# I'm trying to make my unity program, detect the terrain, and change the footsteps/ambience, but the code I've found to detect it, is not compiling

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, compiler-errors

I'm building my first game, with a couple of mates, And while i've got some small experience in C, I'm completely new to C.

I went to set it up in my FPS Controller, but it's telling me that
2 of my errors are "Only assignment, call, increment, decrement, and new object expressions can be used as statements". While 6 of them are just unexpected symbols.

I'll paste the Ide links below.

In the small section,
Line 8, has one of the first errors, and 2 of the unexpected symbol.
Line 10, also has 2 of the unexpected symbol.

Comment: Here is the full code,
https://ideone.com/Xe5nHY

And here is a small section of it,
https://ideone.com/SBerSx

Answer (score 2):

Perhaps you are confused when copied code.. You should replace this symbols `&lt`, `&gt` with correct. `&lt;` matches to the [less-than sign](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Less-than_sign) ( < ) and `&gt;` matches to the [greater-than sign](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Greater-than_sign) ( > )

Here is correct code:

```
for (int n=0; n < mix.Length; ++n)
{
   if (mix[n] > maxMix)
   {
       maxIndex = n;
       maxMix = mix[n];
   }
}
```